# Right command for deploy dll

Tags: 2016, windows-server-2016

Hi I compiled a dll with .netframework 4.6 and want to deploy to a server ,which has sharepoint 2016 and windows server 2016 ,what is the right command and path for deploy this dll to assembly gac folder.

In windows server 2016

I want PowerShell Command for deploy this DLL.
I want to deploy to C:\Windows\assembly folder

when I go to this path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly I found three folders, from this which one is the correct path for assemblies

GAC_32
GAC_64
GAC_MSIL

Comment: is that dll for SharePoint? i mean, will sharepoint use it? or this is part of any wsp/ solution?

Comment: yes a custom web service deploy under layouts folder in  all SharePoint web applications

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to deploy the dll to GAC with the following powershell commands:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish
$publish.GacInstall("FULL PATH TO DLL")
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to check if the dll has been deployed, you can do it with the following powershell command (just replace the values for DllName, Version, Culture and PublicKeyToken with your own values):

```
[reflection.assembly]::Load("DllName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX")
```

Comment: Hi how to verify that DLL installed in server GAC folder by command or location?

Comment: Please check my updated answer.

Comment: when i deploy can i use the same PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a or use with which come with dll?

Comment: No, you have to use the values of your dll. This value (PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) is the public key from System.EnterpriseServices dll.

Comment: when i try to check assembly i got below error
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly ' Version=1.3.6.2, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."